# Adding Quesry string to Facebook fan page app

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I have integrated a e-commerce site in my facebook fan page via page tab
https://www.facebook.com/Thesoftwareguy7/app_687345671301257

the problem it I want too append some custom url to it
https://www.facebook.com/Thesoftwareguy7/app_687345671301257?f=1

but when I parse the URL it gives me 
Array ( [scheme] => https [host] => s-static.ak.facebook.com [path] => /platform/page_proxy/hv09mZVdEP8.js )

It worked perfectly in facebook apps when i append it in apps.facebook.com/687345671301257/

But it does not work in facebook fanpage custom tab.

Thanks for your time?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at the `app_data` field in the `signed_request`? The docs are here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/#integrating

This would result in a Page Tab URL of https://www.facebook.com/Thesoftwareguy7/app_687345671301257?app_data=f%3D1

You then have to decode the `app_data` parameter to get the key/value.

Comment: I am able to get this. Its a fstore and i am setting cancel, cancel_return url in paypal code, so I need to set it
https://www.facebook.com/Thesoftwareguy7/app_687345671301257?action=<dynamic>

but i cant detect. How can i use app_data? please refer me to that part.

Comment: You're using the wrong parameter in your example URL! Like I wrote, you need to use `app_data` as single querystring parameter and encode you "real" querystring in that one.

Comment: i am having another problem with javascript sdk.. Every thing is working fine except when I try to add more permission it wont show in popup i.e. as for permission expect email.

Comment: [code]
FB.login(function(response) {
     if (response.authResponse) 
     {
       getUserInfo();
     } else 
     {
    console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
      }
   },{
   scope: "email,user_hometown,user_location,user_photos",
   return_scopes: true
   });
[/code]